# Opengl nothing is being written to depth buffer

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx, opengl-3

I'm trying to implement depth testing for 2D isometric game. To get something working, I started off with this sample, but I cannot get it to work correctly.

I'm trying to draw 2 images in a specific order.

first.png

[image]

second.png

[image]

first.png is drawn first, and second.png is drawn on top. Using fragment shader, I compute that red color has lower depth than green color, hence green fragments should be discarded when drawn on top of red fragments. The end result is that when second.png is drawn directly on top of first.png, the resulting square colored only red.

At the end of render function, I get the pixels of depth buffer, and looping over them I check if the values have been changed from defaults ones. It seems that no matter what I do, the values in depth buffer never change.

The depth test itself is working, if I set green fragments to depth=1.0, red fragments to depth=0.0 and my depth function is GL_LESS, only red fragments are drawn, but the depth buffer is not changed.

The code is in Java, but OpenGL functions are the same.

```
    private SpriteBatch mBatch;

private Texture mTexture1;
private Texture mTexture2;

@Override
public void create() {

    mBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    mBatch.setShader(new ShaderProgram(Gdx.files.internal("test.vsh"), Gdx.files.internal("test.fsh")));

    mTexture1 = new Texture("first.png");
    mTexture2 = new Texture("second.png");

    Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    Gdx.gl20.glDepthFunc(GL20.GL_LESS);
    Gdx.gl20.glDepthMask(true);

}

@Override
public void render() {

    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    mBatch.begin();

    float scale = 4.0f;

    float x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2;
    float y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2;

    mBatch.draw(mTexture1, x - mTexture1.getWidth() / 2 * scale, y - mTexture1.getHeight() / 2 * scale,
            mTexture1.getWidth() * scale, mTexture1.getHeight() * scale);

    mBatch.flush();

    mBatch.draw(mTexture2, x - mTexture2.getWidth() / 2 * scale, y - mTexture2.getHeight() / 2 * scale,
            mTexture2.getWidth() * scale, mTexture2.getHeight() * scale);

    mBatch.end();

    int width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    int height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.newFloatBuffer(width * height);
    Gdx.gl20.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL20.GL_FLOAT,
            buffer);

    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
        float pixel = buffer.get(i);
        if (pixel != 1.0f && pixel != 0.0f) {
            // why is this never thrown??
            // it means depth buffer wasn't changed.
            throw new IllegalStateException("OMG IT WORKS!! " + pixel);
        }
    }

    if (Gdx.gl20.glGetError()!=0) {
        throw new Error("OPENGL ERROR: " + Gdx.gl20.glGetError());
    }
}
```

Vertex shader

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * vec4(a_position, 1);
    v_color = a_color * 2.0;
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord0;
}
```

Fragment shader

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main()
{

    vec4 texel = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);

    if (texel.r > texel.g)
    {
        gl_FragDepth = 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        gl_FragDepth = 0.5;
    }


    gl_FragColor = texel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem.

SpriteBatch.begin() does

glDepthMask(false)

Setting glDepthMask to false prevents OpenGL from writing to depth buffer.

The solution is to call glDepthMask(true) after SpriteBatch.begin()